# Manage repo size by removing obsolete package versions

Tags: repository, rpm, suse, zypper

We have a custom Suse Linux Enterprise repository, that we want to ship to customers in the future. In there right now are a lot of different versions of the same packages, some obsolete and some needed as a dependency for other packages, so the whole repo is quite large.

I guess what im trying to do, is find a query to list all packages that have newer versions in the repository, and have no other package that needs this version as a dependency.

Is there an elegant way, to find the not needed packages ?